# IIS7 Java application writing files with size 0

Tags: java, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I am running microstrategy business intelligece software on IIS7. It is an ASPX application with java backend. I am not exactly sure of the architecture behind Java->ASPX.

I have developed some extension for this software which includes xml and kml files being written to the IIS web application directory. However when these files are written to this directory they are of size 0. If I alter the code and write to D: they are written properly and have content. I altered the permissions on the IIS application directory to have FC for the everyone group. Are there any other permissions or settings in IIS which needs to be altered? I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Did you remember to "close()" your File(s)? I don't think it's permission related (or you wouldn't even get 0 byte files).

Comment: The files are being created with the JAK KML library. I think there are methods inside of the KML.marshall() function which close the file writer. but maybe it doesnt, Ill look into that.

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267393/kml-marshal-produces-zero-length-files) question?

Comment: KML.marhsal() returns true in working environment, in non working it returns false.